# Merge [database] and [db] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Checking the stats

- [db](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/db) - 3 questions
- [database](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) - 192 questions

Can these be merged? It doesn't make sense to have both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now complete: [db](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/db) is now a synonym of [database](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database).

Answer (score 2):

I've retagged the `db` questions with the `database` tag. Easy enough, since there were only three of them. It probably wouldn't hurt to have a tag synonym in place, just to eliminate the redundancy.